# Impossible to log in to developer.yahoo.com

Tags: yahoo-api

If I click the Sign In on the top right of [developer.yahoo.com](https://developer.yahoo.com), I am able to sign in successfully but the page is redirected to `www.yahoo.com`. I can read mail.

If I go to [developer.yahoo.com/apps](https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/) (even if I have successfully signed in using the previous step) I am directed to the sign-in page, but even if the right credentials are entered, it always returns to the *same* sign-in page (without no indications of error) as shown below:

[image]

If I go to https://ydn.vanillaforums.com/ and click the Sign In link on the right, I can sign in without error but am returned to `https://ydn.vanillaforums.com/` with the Sign In link still there.

I am in a fix. Being unable to sign in to YDN, I am unable to post this question to the forum there. What have I done wrong? Must my Yahoo account be first enabled for the developer network or has Yahoo shut down the developer service?

Thinking it might be a network problem, I tried VPN from different parts of the world but to no avail.  As a result, I am unable to generate a consumer key/secret for my app.